Probando Sweet Alert
Estoy intentando probar SweetAlert. El programa está compuesto de un archivo html, un PHP y un js. No sé dónde tengo el error. Dejo aquí el código a ver dónde está el error. No sé porque no me sale la alerta.
Fichero: index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
    <title>Sweet Alert</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="formulario" method="post" action = "action.php">
        <input type = "date" name = "start_date">
        <input type = "date" name = "end_date"> 
        <input type ="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>

    <script src="sweet.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>

Fichero: action.php
<?php     
    $start_date = $_POST["start_date"];
    $end_date = $_POST["end_date"];

    if ($start_date > $end_date){        
        echo "<script language='javascript'> saludo(); </script>";        
    }

?>

Fichero: sweet.js
function saludo (){      
    
    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Good job!',
        text: 'You clicked the button!',
        icon: 'success'
});
};


Si eso fuera algun tipo de llamada ajax, pues vale, quizás te funcionaria, porque ya tendrias cargado el script en el head, pero lo que haces aquí es simplemente llamar a una función en un nuevo documento el cual no tiene cargados los mismos scripts que el formulario

Varios errores.
En el action de tu form debes tener cargado el HTML y SweetAlert, además hay un espacio en tu función y las fechas no se comparan así, las debes transformar a objetos tipo fecha
Acá te dejo tu código ejecutado en el mismo archivo
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Parser</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Jquery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-pvPw+upLPUjgMXY0G+8O0xUf+/Im1MZjXxxgOcBQBXU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>

    <!-- CSS Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <br><br>
    <div class="container">
        <form name="formulario" method="POST" action = "">
            <input type = "date" name = "start_date">
            <input type = "date" name = "end_date">
            <input type ="submit" value="Enviar">
        </form>
    </div>
    <!-- JS -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function saludo(){
            Swal.fire({
                icon: "error",
                title: "Oops...",
                text: "Fecha inicial mayor que la fecha final"
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
<?php
if ($_POST) {
    $start_date = date($_POST["start_date"]);
    $end_date = date($_POST["end_date"]);

    if ($start_date > $end_date){
        echo "<script language='javascript'>saludo();</script>";
    }
}
?>

Resultado

Analízalo, espero te ayude a aprender 
